# iOS Clips AI Integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, rule-engine, clips

I am trying to integrate Clips AI engine in my iOS App. I followed the steps given JCL in this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/clipsesg/Birk6kK8opk). But i am stuck in integrating the clips framework in a separate project. I am not sure what architecture and SDK should be set for building the framework for iOS.Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

I uploaded an Xcode 4.6 project (clips_mab_ios_0_1.zip) at https://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsrules/files/CLIPS/Misc/. It shows how to link the CLIPS code into a static library, load a CLIPS file containing rules, and redirect output to a UITextView.

Comment: Could you provide some links to online tutorial on the same.

Comment: Then how do we learn this is? I saw your code but i need more info on what's really happening.

I want to start from the scratch and integrate the rules engine in iOS searched the internet but no luck till now on how do you get this rolling with objective C

Comment: The 70 or so lines of integration code is in AppDelegate.m. The key portion of that code is the addition of a CLIPS I/O router that's described in section 7 of the CLIPS Advanced Programming Guide: http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/documentation/v630/apg.htm

Comment: There are some newer Xcode 6.3 examples here: http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/CLIPSiOS.html